# How can we run Selenium Test suite on a Server

Tags: selenium-rc

I have 3 test Suites Test 1,Test 2 and Test 3.

Each test Suite has 10 test Cases written in TESTNG-JAVA Code.

I want to keeps these as a GUI buttons Test1,Test2 and Test and the suite should run whenever i click the Button and this be done remotely from anywhere.Please help me in doing this.

Answer (score 0):

i make one assumption from your question which is, you want to select your test suites from button 1,2 and 3 in a browser.

so, the basic to your question is

1) you need to deploy your test NG container onto Servlet Container( ex.. Tomcat)

if you have already created a TestSuite using XML files, then follow this,

1A) in a servlet

tng = new TestNG();

List suites=Lists.newArrayList ();

suites.add("THIS IS A PATH TO YOUR XML FILE MUST BE SUPPLIED TO THE SERVLET FROM YOUR WEB PAGE CLICK OF A BUTTON ");

[[ EX : suites.add(request.getParameter("PathToXmlFileName"); this xml path should be supplied from HTML file ]]

and then

tng.setTestSuites(suites);

tng.run();

---

if you don't have physical XML files

2) create a synthetic or dynamic physical xml file using TestNG or XML DOM API given in Java respectively

i have given you the basic idea that you could start with.make use of Listeners given by TestNG which is more powerful and i have implemented Synthetic model which is more dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

As you have created code in java so you can run it from dos/shell prompt.

just fire the command from your web page to cmd/shell.